# Add Angular Js in PrimeFaces - JSF

Tags: angularjs, jsf, primefaces, primeng

I have already a project of JSF with PrimeFaces but now i need to add angular js in my project.
There are tags of primefaces so I don't know how to use primefaces with angular.

So please provide any demo or documentation to implement the Angular with primefaces.

Comment: http://angularprime.appspot.com/

Comment: Primefaces already developed PrimeNG  http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/

Comment: Thank you @SubodhJoshi,
Can you give me a steps to install this PrimeNG?
Because i'm not able to understand the steps it's like NPM and all.
So can you please give me a simple steps.

Comment: @yogeshjalodara I have added details in answer section

Comment: I responded to a -very- similar question here about `angular2`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984827/can-we-use-primeng-in-jsf-without-npm

Answer (score 8):

Primefaces already developed [PrimeNG](http://primefaces.org/primeng) But do not confuse PrimeNG is not the extension of JSF components. PrimeNG used AngularFaces to create PrimeNG components ?

**What is PrimeNG ?**

PrimeNG is a collection of rich UI components for AngularJS2. PrimeNG is a sibling of the popular PrimeFaces and its free to use under Apache License 2.0, a commercial friendly license. It has the same look and feel as the PrimeFaces components, so integration on that part should be (almost?) seamless.

**For Setup**

You have to follow the following link [PrimeNG Setup](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup)

**Quickstart**

An example starter application based on angular2-quickstart is available at [GitHub](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng-quickstart).

**PrimeNG PRO Support**

1. Premium Layouts and Themes for PrimeNG
2. PrimeNG PRO is a term based commercial support service

Currently  **PrimeNG 0.9** Released last  March 28, 2016

**Roadmap**

Next version is 1.0.0-beta1 and we’ll do a couple of beta releases to bring the upcoming features including drag drop utils, google maps component, datatable enhancements, requests from PrimeNG users and more. Our aim is to sync the 1.0 release with the 1.0 final release of Angular2.

Comment: very nice explanation

Comment: Or even go for AngularFaces

Comment: @Kukeltje I think PFNG is better option than using AngularFaces directly

Comment: PrimeNG is for plain AngularJS, No integration/relation whatsoever with JSF (e.g. reusing beans/controllers etc. And it is not a sibbling of JavaServerFaces, but a sibbling of PrimeFaces, but again... no integration, besides look and feel

Comment: @Kukeltje Agree with you.But i am currently using Both PF and PFNG in one of my project both working fine.So may be there could be some issue but upto today i did not find anything and agree Integration not possible its just like adding a third party API

Comment: Hi All,
I need to make a fresh project for the admin section.
And I don't know installation of PFNG.
I'm not aware with "npm install".
And can you please tell me please?

Comment: @yogeshjalodara Did u Read Single word which i wrote in my answer ? Did u click on link i added ? If not no one can help you. And dear no one will create the project for you.I have added setup link please have a look it have all the details.

Comment: @SubodhJoshi I have checked everything.
But if i have PF project then can i integrate the PFNG into the PF project?

Comment: @yogeshjalodara Read Kukeltje  comment PrimeNG  is extension of AngularJS Its not the extension of JSF Component like Primefaces..Please dont confuse between these two library .PrimeNG not the extension of JSF Its a Library which extend AngularFaces.But we can use PrimeNG with Primefaces its a Library which can be use with JSF.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below lines in angular-cli.json.

```
"styles": [
        "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
        "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/lightness/theme.css",
        "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "styles.css"
      ]
```

OR 
Copy & paste css from the themes file to style.css