# Is possible to use Primeng, Angular2 embedded in JSF without npm?

Tags: angular, jsf, primeng

I want to use angular2 framework for frontend, so for UI part I want to use primeng but I don't know how npm works.

Tech info:

1. My IDE is eclipse/netbeans
2. project is going to be deployed on Wildfly8.0

Can I mix JSF components with primeng?

Comment: It is not clear to me if you want to avoid npm completely  or just during the build process. Once you have downloaded the packages you are free to copy the files you want into your project.

Answer (score 13):

**TL;DR: Yes it is possible, but there are better alternatives**

Important concepts:

- `AngularJS` is a synonym for angular version 1
- `Angular2` is synonym for angular version 2 (not backwards compatible with v1)
- `primeng` is a components library that depends on `angular2`
- `primefaces` is a components library that depends on `JSF`
- `JSF` and `angular2` are MVC frameworks, where each one has injection mechanisms based on annotations (@annotation) although the terminology is similar the underneath of both mechanisms is very different
- `angular2` + `primeng` is used with `typescript` (recommended) or `javascript`, on the other hand, `JSF` + `primefaces` is used with `java`
- `primeng` is client-side, `primefaces` is server-side
- the company developing `primeng` is the same company developing `primefaces`, and recently we as users have seen a very good synergy, where if there is an improvement in one component is then ported to the other library.
- Right now (2016) `primefaces` has more components than `primeng` and feels more polished

Implications of using `primeng` + `JSF` (`primefaces`):

- Each framework has different lifecycles with different concepts and implications (given that one is client-side and the other is server-side), if you start to use both frameworks you *have to* understand them at great detail.
- If you start mixing components of both frameworks this is going to be very hard to maintain

Other approaches:

- `primeng` + `JAX-RS`: Given that you are using `wildfly` this will be easy to implement, all services provide the info to the client components. It tends to be the 'modern' approach.
- `JSF` + `primefaces`: this is the simplest solution, only server side, only one framework to learn.
- use `JSF` only as a template engine (facelets) and on top of it use `angular2` + `primeng`: yes, this could work but needs more investigation to make it properly, you need to really understand `JSF` and `angular2` lifecycles, is not impossible but requires time.

As for you other question about `npm`:  Yes, you can use `angular2` without `npm`, but you will need to write more boilerplate code than necessary, you can use this plunker as starting point (you need to add the js file for `primeng`): http://plnkr.co/edit/bApfY9?p=info.

---

Update 1: 
I once read that `JSF` was planning to implement a lifecycle phase to execute javascript code. No official statement by now.

Comment: Thanks for your response.The information you have give is very helpful to me.

Comment: Glad to help you!